# Using a manifest file when debugging a project using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, manifest

I am using java and Eclipse, and I want to create a Splashscreen.
I found this example, which is very nice: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

But it means using a manifest file. I could get it to run if I export the project to a jar file and then run it, but I would like to debug it in Eclipse because it is behaving strangely.

Is there any way that I can create an Manifest, add to my project and tell Eclipse to use that manifest every time I click in the Debug button?

ps: I have already seen a thread here where someone recommended am ant file. This ant file generates a jar, but it is not called when I click on "Debug" in Eclipse.

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read the tutorial page you linked to : the answer is in there :

> To display a splash screen from the command line use the -splash: command-line argument. This argument is a Java application launcher option that displays a splash screen:

```
java -splash:<file name> <class name>
```

So you just have to edit your debug configuration in Eclipse and add the -splash: argument

Comment: Hi! I didn't even know that is is possible (defining these parameters in Eclipse), I will take a look at it! Thanks!

Comment: Where did you put this in the Debug configuration?. Program arguments or VM Arguments?...